# Various icons now missing

Tags: system, icons, photos

I turned on my Elementary OS Panetheon desktop yesterday evening to discover various icons were missing, 'Photos', "Videos". Also the System settings icon has changed to what looks like some little boxes. Some of the mini icons in the system tray are also broken.

I have tried uninstalling & reinstalling 'Photos' but the issue remained, actually in the App centre the icon is also missing.

Anyone have an idea how I can restore my icons?

Many thanks.

E

Comment: Have you tried this? In the “about” window for elementary OS 0.4, there’s a small button here to “Restore Default Settings”, if you messed with some system or interface settings and would like to go back to the default ones, just click this button.